# Unison synchronization between host and virtual machine server

Tags: ssh, virtual-machine, unison

I am trying to set up unison to synchronize directories between my host OS and a virtual OS. I can ssh from my host terminal with no problems. When Unison tries to ssh, I get "Fatal error: Lost connection with the server.". Some more details:

I have set up a virtual machine (based on the the Cloudera VM-4.1.1 virtual machine) on my host system (Ubuntu 14.01) using Oracle VM Virtualbox.

I set up the network settings in the VirtualBox manager so that I can ssh to the virtual machine from my host machine.(under Settings>Network, I set Adapter 1 Attached to Bridged Adapter) 
[image]

With this setting, I can successfully ssh to the virtual machine from my host terminal, but unison produces the error mentioned above.

Here is the unison profile file:

```
    # Unison preferences
    label = Synchronize to code and data of cloudera hadoop VM
    root = /some/local/path
    root = ssh://username@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx//some/remote/path
    sshargs = -C
```

where some/local/path, some/remote/path, and xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx all have valid values. Any ideas?

PS: I am sorry if this is off-topic. I was unsure where to place it.

Comment: Does Unison work alright if you try to sync to a non-virtual server? What is the result of running `unison profile -testserver`?

Comment: The machine on which I was doing all this has been down due to GPU failure, so cannot check `-testserver` option at the moment. However, Unison was  synchronizing with non-virtual server with no problems.

Comment: So I just successfully got Unison (2.40.63) to sync to an Ubuntu VM from my Ubuntu host using a profile precisely like yours without any hiccups and without any errors. I suspect then that the error is coming either from some weird issue with the Cloudera VM, or more likely from something in in the way ssh is configured on the Cloudera VM (did you install ssh-server yourself on the VM or was it preconfigured by Cloudera?). I would look in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` for any weird settings that would cause this (or just install ssh-server fresh and see if the error persists).